# AttributeError: module 'dask' has no attribute 'system'

Tags: python, attributes, jupyter, dask, attributeerror

I am running Jupyter Notebooks on a computing cluster and in my notebook have installed the full version of dask (version 2.0.0) without it throwing any errors using:

```
!pip install dask[complete] --user
```

But, I get an error when I run the following code:

```
cat = col.search(experiment_id=['lgm'], table_id='Omon', variable_id='thetao',
                 grid_label='gn')
datasets = cat.to_dataset_dict()
```

The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-9aec78aebd9f> in <module>
----> 1 datasets = cat.to_dataset_dict()
      2 datasets
      3 list(datasets.keys())

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/intake_esm/core.py in to_dataset_dict(self, zarr_kwargs, cdf_kwargs, preprocess, storage_options, progressbar, aggregate)
    923 
    924         self._datasets = {}
--> 925         with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=dask.system.CPU_COUNT) as executor:
    926             future_tasks = [
    927                 executor.submit(_load_source, key, source) for key, source in sources.items()

AttributeError: module 'dask' has no attribute 'system'
```

Other similar questions here on StackOverflow (about other attributes) say that such attributes are definitely included in the dask module (especially since I was sure to install the complete version of dask), so this error suggests I don't have my environment set up correctly. Please could someone explain what this means and how to resolve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: As a follow-up, I've just done ```help(dask)``` and seen that 'system' is not listed under 'Package Contents'. A friend just now installed dask the same way I did and for him it installed dask version 2.3.0 (whereas mine is 2.0.0) and he has 'system' listed under 'Package Contents' and I do not. Perhaps this is why I'm getting my error, but I still don't know how to install the latest version of dask or why it didn't automatically install the latest version of dask.

Comment: Dask is now on `calver` system, is there a reason why `2021.6.2` is not installed? https://pypi.org/project/dask/

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being an environment problem on my end. I was updating dask but to a different environment than the one I was operating on.

Short story: updating dask fixed it! Thank you and sorry for the silly problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your version of dask was released on Jun 25, 2019, so you are two years out of date. That sometimes doesn't matter, but intake-esm is a relatively new and actively developed project, so it tends to use more cutting-edge versions of its dependencies.

Short story: please update dask! You may want a venv or conda environment for the task, if there are things in your current environment that can't handle upgrading.